# Add external volume app folder to Launchpad

Tags: hard-drive, symbolic-link, osx-mavericks, ln, launchpad

I have a primary volume and secondary volume which I store apps on in a folder called *HDD Applications*. Launchpad only looks at the */Applications* folder on the primary drive for apps. 
How can I get Launchpad to also use the *HDD Applications* on the other drive when showing apps?

I have tried symlinking the directories with `ln -s "/Volumes/Macintosh HDD/HDD Applications/" "/Applications/HDD Applications"`
but that does not work and would like to not have to symlink each individual app.